# Rails: Comment Pagination under a Micropost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, pagination

I have a comment model under a micropost. I was wondering if I can paginate this so that 50 comments won't show all at once once the comment button is clicked on the micropost. I am pretty sure this cannot be paginated but is there a way that like facebook, only a certain amount shows and then the user can show more if they please. Currently my code looks like this:

**Micropost HTML for the Comment Section**

```
<div id='CommentContainer-<%= micropost.id%>' class='CommentContainer Condensed2'>
<div class='Comment'>
<%= render :partial => "comments/form", :locals => { :micropost => micropost } %>
</div>
<div id='comments'>
<%=render micropost.comments %>
</div>
</div>
```

When a button above is clicked it shows this section and I would not like 50 comments to show up all at once. All suggestions will be very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure you are calling `@comments = Comment.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)` in your controller
2. You render the group through the `<%= will_paginate @comments %>` call and not through `:render` and then later through `will_paginate`
3. Since I already know you are using nested partials. I would make sure that the item you are calling has the correct collection. After those three things are met, it should be working fine.

You can also be sure to checkout the railscast on [will_paginate](http://railscasts.com/episodes/51-will-paginate-revised) although without a pro subscription you may have to watch the [outdated version](http://railscasts.com/episodes/51-will-paginate).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help for the past couple of problems :)...The only issue I am currently receiving is that when replacing the `<%=render micropost.comments %>` with `<%= will_paginate @comments %>` I get the same pagination numbers on the bottom of the comment section but no comments show up

Comment: Ah, you might not actually need to use `@comments` there. try using 
`<%= will_paginate micropost.comments %>` that might work. I just used @comments because I wasn't sure what variables you had available.

Comment: New error! x) `undefined method `total_pages' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fc8c1e2fa90>`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to lookup 2 rails gems that are most widely used for pagination on rails

--> [will paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate)

--> [Kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari)

I prefer Kaminari over will paginate because it offers a lot more flexibility than will paginate.

Comment: I am currently using paginate for the microposts on the user show page but I don't think it is possible to paginate the comments that are under the microposts along with the microposts pagainating on the user show page

Comment: You can paginate anything you want. All you need is to set a limit on the number of items to be shown per page